# CSS select tag without first-child

Tags: css

With CSS I want to select the *li* without description, without *first-child =  b* ,  to apply a padding-letf  on the li without title
HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><b>title</b>description</li>
    <li><b>title</b>description</li>
    <li>description without title</li>
    <li><b>title</b>description</li>
</ul>
```

something like

```
ul li:not[first-child=b]
```

PS: I cannot add a class to the different li

thank you

Comment: you can set margin-left: 10px for li tag, then set margin-left: -10px for li > b:first-child

Comment: Are you using bootstrap in the project? If yes then i have another better solution.

Comment: no I hate bootstrap :-)

Comment: @ErickBoileau , lol ok. However i am adding the solution.

Comment: I suggest you use dl and dt for this specific case. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyXmGq

Comment: I cannot change the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select list-items based on content till now. However if the goal is just to apply a `padding-left` on the li without title HTML, you can do it as follows:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

li > b:first-child {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><b>title</b>description</li>
  <li><b>title</b>description</li>
  <li>description without title</li>
  <li><b>title</b>description</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks it work perfectly
best answer

Comment: @ErickBoileau you are welcome)

Comment: @ErickBoileau please accept best answer that solved your problem... so that others can take help from it as well...

Comment: I have no idea how to set the best answer

Comment: @ErickBoileau Just mark the tick icon appearing below answer votes to accept it.

Comment: thanks ! I've marked the first answer with margin-left

Answer (score 1):

this is impossible with css due to the way browser is matching selectors - you cannot select element by something that is inside of it... however, it might be available in the future

Comment: thank you

this feature is really missing

Comment: any reason for downvote?

Comment: downvote ?  I did nothing, and it is certainly the best answer

i have certainly click on tne arrow to go to the top or bottom of the page :-)

Comment: yeah but someone did :)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround, if it helps anyway:

```
ul{
    padding-left:5px;
}
li > b{
    margin-left:-5px;
}
```